# Refresh page content on clicking the item second time in drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using drawer navigation in which first time on selecting an item for example contacts loading contacts and next time when i select contacts again from drawer navigation the contacts page is not reloading the contacts page remains in previous state.

i have tries NavigationEvents but it is not calling .